# Comma Operator with indexing 2D arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, graph-theory, comma-operator

I have this algorithm that is pseudocode for the dijkstra algorithm for graph theory. The first thing that goes on is a basic for loop.

```
visitedSet[0] = true //visitedSet is a array of bools
for (int i = 1; i <= numberNodes; ++i)
{
    distanceArray[i] = adjacencyMatrix[0,i];
    //distanceArray is 1D with size of fifty
    //adjacencyMatrix is 2D with size of fifty
    //Both arrays hold values of unsigned ints
}
```

Here are the array definitions

```
enum GraphLimit300 {MAX_NODES = 50};
unsigned int adjacencyMatrix[MAX_NODES][MAX_NODES];
unsigned int distanceArray[MAX_NODES];
```

Visual studio is giving me an array saying that I can't assign an array of unsigned integers to a pointer. I have looked up online that with the comma operator basically in this case throws out the first case, `0`, and treats it as `distanceArray[i] = adjacencyMatrix[i];` Which doesn't make sense to me since `adjacenyMatrix` is a 2D array. I am just wondering what is giving me this compile error and get more information on why, because I basically just copying in variable names where the pseudo code basically says to.

Pseudo code:

```
    S = { 1 }
for ( index = 2; index <= N; ++ index )
    D[ index ] = C[ 1, index ]
for ( index = 1; index <= N – 1; ++ index )
    Choose a vertex v in V – S such that D[ v ] is a minimum
    Add v to S
    for each vertex w in V – S do
        D[ w ] = min( D[ w ], D[ v ] + C[ v, w ] )
```

The above pseudo code uses lists to represent their arrays they for some reason start at 1 so I modified it to start at 0 in my code.

Comment: You don't show us the declarations of `distanceArray` and `adjacencyMatrix`, which renders your question unanswerable.

Comment: I threw in comments in the first code block literally saying how they are declared. I will put that in a separate code block now. @CareyGregory

Comment: `[0,i]` <-- I don't know why you're doing this at all. It serves no possible purpose and looks like you just made a typo when you meant to type `[0][i]`.

Comment: @CareyGregory There might be a typo in the pseudo code I have. I know everyone that has posted here is right.

Comment: Some languages do use the `[x,y]` syntax for indexing double arrays so you might see that in pseudocode, but you shouldn't expect pseudocode to use the proper syntax of any language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to review how to access elements of 2D array. Also, take look at what [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) does. You have to use `[]` twice:

```
adjacencyMatrix[0][i]
```

The following:

```
adjacencyMatrix[0, i]
```

is equivalent to:

```
adjacencyMatrix[i]
```

Which will still leave you with 1D array. And, as the error message says:

```
   distanceArray[i] = adjacencyMatrix[i];
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//   unsigned int   array of unsigned ints
```

You can not possibly expect this assignment to happen.

Comment: And just get rid of the comma operator. It serves no purpose other than to obfuscate the code.

Comment: Like I said I already knew what the comma operator does, which in this statement `distanceArray[i]` will be assigned a pointer. Which is giving me a compile error.

Comment: @DrakeJacks Of course it is because you're trying to assign an array (a pointer) to `distanceArray[i]`, which is simply an `unsigned int.`

Comment: @LogicStuff Your comment says `distanceArray` is a `bool` but it's an `unsigned int`.