# Use function to create and free 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I practice the 2D dynamic array with reference to the URL below：
https://thispointer.com/allocating-and-deallocating-2d-arrays-dynamically-in-c-and-c/

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** create_2d_arr(int row_size,int colum_size)
{
    int** array = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*row_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i++)
        array[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*colum_size);  
    return array;
}

void free_2d_arr(int** matrix,int row_size, int colum_size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i++) {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int row=3,cloum=2;
    int** arr_2d = create_2d_arr(row,cloum);

    arr_2d[0,0]=4;
    arr_2d[0,1]=5;

    arr_2d[1,0]=6;
    arr_2d[1,1]=7;

    arr_2d[2,0]=8;
    arr_2d[2,1]=9;

    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<cloum;j++)
    printf("arr_2d[%d,%d] = %d \n",i,j,arr_2d[i,j]);

    free_2d_arr(arr_2d,row,cloum);

    return 0;
}
```

However, there are errors when executing after compilation:

```
arr_2d[0,0] = 8 
arr_2d[0,1] = 9 
arr_2d[1,0] = 8 
arr_2d[1,1] = 9 
arr_2d[2,0] = 8 
arr_2d[2,1] = 9 
[1]    9300 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./t
```

Only arr_2d[2,0]=8 arr_2d[2,1]=9 are correct.
I don't understand where my code is wrong.
Does anyone help me?

---

### renew

thanks for your replies.
but after I modify `arr_2d[2,0]=8` to a`rr_2d[2][0]=8` ...

```
result of printf is
arr_2d[0][0] = -267545984
arr_2d[0][1] = -267545952
arr_2d[1][0] = -267545984
```

### ...

### warning of compiler

```
t.c:38:47: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    printf("arr_2d[%d,%d] = %d \n",i,j,arr_2d[i,j]);
                                              ^
t.c:38:40: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'int *' [-Wformat]
    printf("arr_2d[%d,%d] = %d \n",i,j,arr_2d[i,j]);
                            ~~         ^~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
```

my compiler is clang,even if I use gcc

=========

## Solved

After modify:

```
printf("arr_2d[%d,%d] = %d \n",i,j,arr_2d[i,j]);
```

=>

```
printf("arr_2d[%d,%d] = %d \n",i,j,arr_2d[i],[j]);
```

It work normally.
Thank everyone very much.

Comment: `arr_2d[0,0]=4;` -> `arr_2d[0][0]=4;`

Comment: How many compiler warnings did your compiler give you for this code?

Comment: I would suspect that you did not change it in `printf`.

Comment: Do you use the flags -Wall to turn on extra warnings. I would advise that.

Comment: Hi Osiris, thanks your hints.It work normally.

Comment: Stay clear of crappy internet tutorials. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for how to do it in C. In C++ you would preferably use std::vector.

Comment: the posted code results in a LONG lost of warnings from the compiler.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings  ( for `gcc` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to produce the same output

Comment: this kind of statement: `arr_2d[0,0]=4;` is not valid, suggest: `arr_2d[0][0]=4;`

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `array[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*colum_size);`  1) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, output your error message and the text reason the error occurred to `stderr`.   The easiest way to do that is by calling `perror( "your error message" );`  2) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer,  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) do not leave out optional opening and closing braces '{' and '}'.

Comment: OT: regarding: `void free_2d_arr(int** matrix,int row_size, int colum_size)`  In this function, the parameter `colum_size` is not used,  To avoid a compiler warning, either remove that parameter or the first statement in the body of the function should be: `(void)colum_size);`

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main(int argc, char const *argv[])`  When the parameters are not going to be used, the correct signature for `main()` is: `int main( void )`  otherwise the compiler will output to warning messages about unused parameters

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `arr_2d[0,1]=5;`  the `[0,1]` is a `comma` expression where the first expresion `1` does nothing.  What you really want is: `arr_2d[0][1]=5;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr_2d[x,y]` is equivalent to `arr_2d[y]`

use `arr_2d[x][y]` in assignment and access

In C (or C++) `a,b,c .., z` compute *a* then *b* .. then *z* and returns the value of *z*

---

So :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** create_2d_arr(int row_size,int colum_size)
{
    int** array = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*row_size);
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < row_size; i++)
        array[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*colum_size);  
    return array;
}

void free_2d_arr(int** matrix,int row_size, int colum_size) {
  int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < row_size; i++) {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int row=3,cloum=2;
    int** arr_2d = create_2d_arr(row,cloum);

    arr_2d[0][0]=4;
    arr_2d[0][1]=5;

    arr_2d[1][0]=6;
    arr_2d[1][1]=7;

    arr_2d[2][0]=8;
    arr_2d[2][1]=9;

    int i,j;
    for( i=0;i<row;i++)
    for( j=0;j<cloum;j++)
    printf("arr_2d[%d][%d] = %d \n",i,j,arr_2d[i][j]);

    free_2d_arr(arr_2d,row,cloum);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is :

```
arr_2d[0][0] = 4 
arr_2d[0][1] = 5 
arr_2d[1][0] = 6 
arr_2d[1][1] = 7 
arr_2d[2][0] = 8 
arr_2d[2][1] = 9
```

Comment: OK,But result looking like incorrect after I modify arr_2d[0][0]=4;arr_2d[0][1]=5;....

Comment: arr_2d[0][0] = -267545984 arr_2d[0][1] = -267545952 ... (result of printf)

Comment: @D.Wei  Are you sure you changed all `[a,b]` to `[a][b]` ?  I do on your program and it works writing : 4 ,5 ... 8, 9 with the prefix `arr_2d[..][..]`

Comment: Hi bruno , see my renew

Comment: @D.Wei I edited my answer to put the corrected version I executed

Comment: @D.Wei I think you missed to also do the change in the printf `printf("arr_2d[%d][%d] = %d \n",i,j,arr_2d[i][j]);`

Comment: OK! Thank your very much!

Answer (score 2):

you can't access array's value like this

```
arr_2d[x,y];
```

you have to use this type of syntax

```
arr_2d[x][y];
```

Comment: Actually you can, but it is not a very helpful way... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098166/comma-operator-with-indexing-2d-arrays

Comment: I don't think you can, what a comma operator does, it it just evaluates each part and return the last evaluated part

so arr_2d[2,23,6,23,56,2] is kinda useless you could just use arr_2d[2] and you'd have the same thing.
Additionally if it's a 2D array, arr_2d[x,y] would return an array of `int/char..`

Comment: [... it it just evaluates each part and return the last evaluated part...], so you can.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
arr_2d[i][j] = n;
```

I have never seen something like `arr_2d[i,j]` and would be great-full if someone explained it to us.

My guess is that it's equivalent to `arr_2d[j]` but I'm not sure.

EDIT: precision: you should change ALL your `arr_2d[i,j]` (like `arr_2d[0,0]`) to the new syntax

Comment: It is probably from something like matlab. Where (i,j) is regular. But with square brackets i havent ever seen it as well

Comment: @hetepeperfan yes that should be it ... I meant that I've never seen it in C ;)

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. incorporates my comments to the OPs question
4. for readability, inserts an appropriate space: inside parens, inside braces, after semicolons, after commas, around C operators
5. used `size_t` rather than `int` to avoid compiler warnings about conversions between `int` and `size_t`, especially in the calls to `calloc()` and `malloc()`

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE


// prototypes
void free_2d_arr( int** matrix, size_t row_size, size_t colum_size );


int** create_2d_arr( size_t row_size, size_t colum_size )
{
    int** array = calloc( row_size, sizeof( int* ) );
    if( !array )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < row_size; i++ )
    {
        array[ i ] = malloc( sizeof(int) * colum_size );  
        if( !array[ i ] )
        {
            perror( "malloc failed" );
            free_2d_arr( array, row_size, colum_size ); 
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    return array;
}


void free_2d_arr( int** matrix, size_t row_size, size_t colum_size ) 
{
    (void)colum_size;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < row_size; i++ ) 
    {
        free( matrix[ i ] );
    }
    free( matrix );
}


int main( void )
{
    size_t row = 3;
    size_t cloum = 2;
    int** arr_2d = create_2d_arr( row, cloum );

    arr_2d[ 0 ][ 0 ] = 4;
    arr_2d[ 0 ][ 1 ] = 5;

    arr_2d[ 1 ][ 0 ] = 6;
    arr_2d[ 1 ][ 1 ] = 7;

    arr_2d[ 2 ][ 0 ] = 8;
    arr_2d[ 2 ][ 1 ] = 9;

    for( size_t i=0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        for( size_t j=0; j < cloum; j++ )
        {
            printf( "arr_2d[%lu,%lu] = %d \n", i, j, arr_2d[ i ][ j ] );
        }
    }

    free_2d_arr( arr_2d, row, cloum );

    return 0;
}
```

a run of the proposed code results in:

```
arr_2d[0,0] = 4 
arr_2d[0,1] = 5 
arr_2d[1,0] = 6 
arr_2d[1,1] = 7 
arr_2d[2,0] = 8 
arr_2d[2,1] = 9
```

Note, however, that the statements:

```
size_t row = 3;
size_t cloum = 2;
```

are really parameters to the program and the `2` and `3` are constants and 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code